# A camada de CrossCutting pode reconhecer a minha camada de Dominio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ddd

A minha dúvida é bem simples.

A minha camada de CrossCutting pode conhecer a minha camada de Dominio? visto que a camada de Repositorio(Data) conhece ela ambas estando dentro da Camada de Infra.

Desculpa a pergunta, pois ainda sou novo no conceito de DDD, estou utilizando o mesmo modelo que eu vi no [vídeo](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/) do Eduardo Pires. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Vamos entender o conceito.

[Cross-cutting](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting) é uma técnica de edição mais frequentemente usada em filmes para estabelecer ações ocorrendo ao mesmo tempo em dois locais diferentes. Em um corte, a câmera vai de uma ação para outra, o que pode sugerir a simultaneidade das duas cenas — mas este não é sempre o caso.

Em ciência da computação, [cross-cutting concerns](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) são aspectos de um programa que afetam outros concerns. Estes concerns, muitas vezes não podem ser decompostos de forma clara do resto do sistema, tanto no projeto e implementação, e podem resultar numa dispersão (duplicação de código), enrolamento (dependências significativas entre os sistemas), ou ambos.

Resumido, a camada de Cross-cutting é bastante usada para os módulos de IOC (Injeção de Dependência), e esses módulos iram precisar saber sobre o seu domínio e outras camadas para fazer a IOC.

No seu exemplo de video do Eduardo Pires ele usar para isso.

O DDD, diz que o desenvolvimento é todo voltado para o Domínio, ou seja as outras camadas podem enxergar o domínio, mas não o inverso.